# How to get unique array whose near values

Tags: php

I have an array.

```
$a = array(
0 => 1,
1 => 1,
2 => 2,
3 => 3,
4 => 1
);
```

How to get unique array like this?

```
$result = array_My_unique($a);
print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
$a = array(
0 => 1,
1 => 2,
2 => 3,
3 => 1
);
```

Thank!

Comment: What are the rules for this? What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I don't think "unique" is what you're looking for. It seems you're trying to remove duplicates that are immediately "next to each other"...?

Comment: Nobody can understand.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying to avoid duplicates that are immediately next to each other:

```
function array_my_unique($a = array()) {
    $out = array();
    $curr = false;
    foreach ($a as $v) {
        if ($curr !== $v) {
            $out[] = $v;
        }
        $curr = $v;
    }
    return $out;
}
```

This satisfies the assertion between input/output that you described in the question.

Comment: I would appreciate a comment about why my answer does not satisfy the parameters of the question to the best of my ability so I can better my answers in the future

Comment: Stackoverflow doesn't like it when someone answers a "bad" question. Your answer per se is fine.

Comment: Thanks guys, just making sure - I could add comments on a line-by-line explanation but it's obvious coding.. maybe could be perceived as "low hanging fruit" but I'd rather take a stab at helping OP